# Can't get rid of the space on top of the page

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I got a white space at the top of my page. I think I messed it up somewhere. I tried everything but I am unable to figure it out.
Can anyone please help me out with this.
Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, this kind of question doesn't fit the format for StackOverflow. Please see the [help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more information.

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't knew that. Anyway, my problem is solved now. Thanks to all the guys for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a non-white-space character in the `<head>` right before `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/mainstyle.css">`

Comment: Thank you very much. That solved the problem. I have been scratching my head for 2 hours to figure this out. How did you find it?

Comment: I used the browsers inspector and once I've found the "" after the body, but other elements in from the <head> as well, I knew that there is an invalid character in the <head> causing early <body> start. In Safari, the view source shows the character with a red dot, so it was pretty easy to find that.

Answer (score 0):

Right below the `<body>` tag you have `""` for some reason, that's what's doing it. It's printing that above everything else. Find that in your code and remove it

Answer (score 0):

[image: Your HTML]

As you can see in image, there is `""` in `<body>` tag. Remove that & issue will get fixed.

One Suggestion: Also, why are you putting CSS/JS in body tag? just move all CSS/JS to `<head>` section.